# Emitting events during debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, envdte

I want to be able to capture intellitrace style calls to a certain method during debugging of my app.

Specifically, each time during debugging when  `MyLibrary.MyClass.MyMethod` is called ideally i'd get a pane of sorts in Visual Studio that would contain the info about the event and the method arguments.

Unfortunately, i need to get it working in Professional edition of Visual Studio (which doesn't have Intellitrace).

I have only tried investigating `EnvDTE80` and there doesn't seem anything suitable at the first glance. 
What would also work is if i could make some custom code run inside the app's app domain while debugging. I could probably use MS Fakes from Enterprise version, generate a shims assembly, place all of debugging into a `ShimsContext` and then re-route my calls.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, right click, select Actions, and you can send a message to the debug output containing all the info you need.

Comment: This is not so bad, for methods that exist in my code. Any ideas of whether i could get the data from the compiled library methods? (e.g. when i dont have their sources to add a breakpoint like that)

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/